# How can I create a HTML table using arrays (vanilla JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I have two arrays:

```
let arr1 = ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'];
let arr2 = ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws'];
```

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    for (let i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        html +='<td>' + arr1[i] + '</td>';  
    }
    html += '<tr/>';
    for (let i=0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        html += '<td class="text-centre">'+ arr2[arr1[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td>';   
    }
    html += '</table>';
```

The **lists will always be the same size** but I am not able to create the table structure I want using **only one** for loop. Any help?

```
<table>
   <tr> 
   <td> lion </td>
   <td> tiger </td> 
   <td> elephant </td>
   <td> snake </td> 
   <td> bear </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td> mane </td>
   <td> stripes </td> 
   <td> trunk </td>
   <td> slither </td> 
   <td> claws </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello AshK, welcome to SO.  So the question is you wanna improve/refactor your function and use only one loop, right?

Comment: What's `times`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without loops at all:

```js
let arr1 = ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'];
let arr2 = ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws'];
let times = {'mane':1, 'stripes':2, 'trunk':3, 'slither':4, 'claws':5};

const html = '<table id="timetable"><tr>'
        + '<td>' + arr1.join('</td><td>') + '</td>'
        + '</tr><tr>'
        + '<td>' + arr2.map(v => times[v.toLowerCase()]).join('</td><td>') + '</td>'
        + '</tr></table>';

console.log(html);
```

And this is the output:

```html
<table id="timetable">
  <tr>
    <td>lion</td>
    <td>tiger</td>
    <td>elephant</td>
    <td>snake</td>
    <td>bear</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I've added `times` and some values there... no idea what data is there for real, that's just an example.

Well, I start to think that `times` and other things were just copy-pasted as an example code you were going to use for your task. So, here is adjusted example without `times`:

```js
let arr1 = ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'];
let arr2 = ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws'];

const html = '<table><tr>'
        + '<td>' + arr1.join('</td><td>') + '</td>'
        + '</tr><tr>'
        + '<td>' + arr2.join('</td><td>') + '</td>'
        + '</tr></table>';

console.log(html);
```

And here is output (actual output is a single string with minimal spacing, this is how it would look like in browser's DOM inspector):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lion</td>
    <td>tiger</td>
    <td>elephant</td>
    <td>snake</td>
    <td>bear</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mane</td>
    <td>stripes</td>
    <td>trunk</td>
    <td>slither</td>
    <td>claws</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And in case you need exactly one loop without dirty tricks like `.join()` or `.map()`, here is the solution (output is same as above):

```js
let arr1 = ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'];
let arr2 = ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws'];

let html1 = '<table><tr>';
let html2 = '</tr><tr>';

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    html1 += '<td>' + arr1[i] + '</td>';
    html2 += '<td>' + arr2[i] + '</td>';
}

const html = html1 + html2 + '</tr></table>';

console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this one should be more clear ?

```js
let arr1 = ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'] 
let arr2 = ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws'] 

createTimeTable( arr1, arr2 )

function createTimeTable()
{
  let TimeTable = document.createElement('table')
  TimeTable.id = 'timetable'

  document.body.appendChild(TimeTable)

  for (arr of arguments) {
    let row = TimeTable.insertRow(-1)
    let c = 0
    for(cell of arr) row.insertCell(c++).textContent = cell
  }
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse}
td    { border: 1px solid grey; padding: .2em .8em }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is a block of code that contains 3 statements: the first initializes the loop for use, the second evaluates a condition to be expressed before each loop iteration, and the third statement is executed as long as the second condition evaluates to `true`.

All 3 statements are optional, as long as you include a semicolon to let the Javascript interpreter know that the defining logic for the `for` loop is elsewhere in the code.

So technically you can create a `for` loop with all 3 statements omitted like so:

```
var i = 0;

for (;;) { 
    if (i > 3) { break; } console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

This can be used to create really complex loops. Be careful though, because  your loop will run indefinitely if your code logic is not defined properly.

When creating a table programmatically, it really is standard practice to use nested `for` loops iterating nested arrays (otherwise known as *multidimensional arrays*), and there's really no reason why you shouldn't:

```
// Create a nested array. Access individual values like multi[...][...]
var multi = [ 
    ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'], 
    ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws']
];
var arr1 = multi[0], arr2 = multi[1];

var table = '<table id = "timetable">';

for (var i = 0; i < multi.length; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < multi[i].length; j++) {
      table += '<td class = "text-centre">' + multi[i][j] + '</td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';
document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

But, if you really *really* want to, you can do it like this, using only one `for` loop:

```
// as you can see, this is way more convoluted and prone to error

// Create a nested array. Access individual values like multi[...][...]
var multi = [ 
    ['lion', 'tiger', 'elephant', 'snake', 'bear'], 
    ['mane', 'stripes', 'trunk', 'slither', 'claws']
];
var table = '<table id = "timetable">';

for (var j = 0, k = 0; j < multi.length; ) { // third statement omitted. will run until j = 2.

    // add a tr at the beginning and end of the table row
    if (k === 0) { table += '<tr>' }

    table += '<td class = "text-centre">' + multi[j][k] + '</td>';

    if (k === (multi[j].length-1)) { 
        k = 0; // reset k to zero for iteration
        table += '</tr>';
        j++; // increment j;
    } else {
        k++;
    }
}
table += '</table>';
document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

`For` loop feferences: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) and  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

P.S., you don't actually need to create a class attribute for every `<td>` element. You can use the CSS 2.1 descendant selector. This will match *every* `td` element nested within `#timetable`, no matter how deeply: `#timetable td { text-align: center; }`